# Meteor flow router and getting params of route in a react component

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs, flow-router

How do I get the params of a route inside a react component
Im using react containers from the react composer package
if this is the whole route

`https://learnbuildrepeat-tevinthuku.c9users.io/ReadProjectMeta/wD98XTTtpf8ceyRJT`

How do I get only

`wD98XTTtpf8ceyRJT`

and store its value in a variable inside a react component.
Ive tried to use

`FlowRouter.getParam()` but it doesnt work. I keep getting undefined

```
import React from 'react';
export default class ReadProjectMetaLayout extends React.Component {
 render() {
 var category = FlowRouter.getQueryParam();
console.log(category);
return (
 <div>
 <h4>Hello World</h4>
 </div>
 )
 }
}
```

this is the route

```
FlowRouter.route("/ReadProjectMeta/:_id", {
name: 'project.meta',
action(params) {
mount(ReadProjectMetaLayoutContainer, {
components: (<ReadProjectMeta  _id={params._id}/>)
})
}
});
```

What could be the problem and how do I solve it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To only get the last part of the string:

```
location.pathname.substr((location.pathname.lastIndexOf('/')+1))
```

Another pure meteor based thing you can try is from [this reference](https://github.com/kadirahq/flow-router/blob/master/README.md#flowroutergetparamparamname):

```
FlowRouter.getParam(":_id");
```

**NOTE:** Your solution didn't work as you are getting query parameter, query parameters are the parameters that are passed in the url after '?'

i.e. */apps/this-is-my-app?show=yes&color=red*

Here in above code color and show are query parameters, while apps is a part of pathname

Comment: I'd say this a more JS solution rather meteor based. The best practice would be to call it in the React state via FlowRouter API.

Comment: @FaysalAhmed : FlowRouter.getParam(":_id"); is a meteor based, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

> - FlowRouter.getParam(paramName) returns the value of a single URL
>   parameter
> - FlowRouter.getQueryParam(paramName) returns the value of a single URL query parameter

Reference:
https://guide.meteor.com/routing.html#accessing-route-info